# API Access Issue in React TypeScript Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm facing an issue with API access in my React TypeScript project. When I first open the site, there is a problem accessing the API used. Interestingly, I need to open the API in a browser for the site to work. However, this solution is not feasible for every client, and it is crucial to keep this information confidential.

Here are my project settings:

```
typescript // setupProxy.ts

import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import { env } from 'process';
import * as authHelper from './core/helpers/storage-helper/AuthHelpers'

module.exports = function (app: any) {
    var customerHotel = authHelper.getHotelCustomer()
    const selectExtApi = customerHotel && customerHotel.externalData?.find((s) => s.isDefault == true)
    var ARPIES_TOKEN_URL = selectExtApi?.url + ':' + selectExtApi?.port
    app.use(
        '/api/**',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: ARPIES_TOKEN_URL, // Replace with your API server's URL
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

> The API dynamically changes, and each customer needs to connect to a
> different API during their initial login. Therefore, I added a proxy
> dynamically, but I'm still experiencing the same issue. I don't
> encounter any problems in the development environment, but when I try
> to open the application from a new computer, the dynamic API doesn't
> work on the first attempt.

first call api not working

```
 TEST_TOKEN_URL = 'http://' + selectExtApi?.url + ':' + selectExtApi?.port;
 const LOGIN_URL = `${TEST_TOKEN_URL }/api/login/login`
  const extlogin = {
        userName: selectExtApi?.userName,
        password: selectExtApi?.password,
    }

    const systemUsr = await axios.post<BaseClass<Result>>(LOGIN_URL, extlogin);
```

How can I resolve this issue? Instead of instructing clients to open the API, how can I make it work automatically?

Thank you!